# Rsa decrypt and using nec

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

```
n = 50142032499469550407421604706771611415193641755639270667473328045908799316205905505167271138079522738272643811917325451177986948493659090203974349370248583120022500722759239305447823602875823849366662503027591858371125301505134216095903796534740686834236150999
e = 65537
c = 45005399504992587510006608300548120810512973768886391125598523343330913326304417790989607300367232977960116381108873363343598357102136548218343380795022179607741940866191404186680657699739176842869814452906110393321567314747096161480003824583613027819960172221
```

I tried with latest [RsaCtfTool](https://github.com/Ganapati/RsaCtfTool/blob/master/RsaCtfTool.py) version and it dosent work, there was a scramble of code

```
Results for /tmp/tmpbsmxslye:

Unciphered data :
HEX : 0x537b762ad879d73fc43bddaefbac97c761cb6d5e8ef8d34c30339efc710692c7fed88d381cea79f3ff4cafc8781102e75d14858a5bf51f30cc3db2a923e11b552a4bb62e8acdca072e05dfa3339f70f8ee9a3ced8c0738285eba90734eb9df2c3edcd3e332accf411e7fb65a
INT (big endian) : 40111651888157165029437328511246711833600341248186328292628445309156564820193142620786063692137415731558387498115042099573352418128558891753633190445868768864754408930988626358562440439393865093780815723595640564016030173945005616779600721173305345226766792282
INT (little endian) : 43585820924199350804413548176714962723022677460493225470148152207527235458621759903227128027823093032467062127172665897388707295045964555327274491674781131407292944716056819091268595652074255353611869391245933441644182846078891061658090469785803825312343423827
STR : b'S{v*\xd8y\xd7?\xc4;\xdd\xae\xfb\xac\x97\xc7a\xcbm^\x8e\xf8\xd3L03\x9e\xfcq\x06\x92\xc7\xfe\xd8\x8d8\x1c\xeay\xf3\xffL\xaf\xc8x\x11\x02\xe7]\x14\x85\x8a[\xf5\x1f0\xcc=\xb2\xa9#\xe1\x1bU*K\xb6.\x8a\xcd\xca\x07.\x05\xdf\xa33\x9fp\xf8\xee\x9a<\xed\x8c\x078(^\xba\x90sN\xb9\xdf,>\xdc\xd3\xe32\xac\xcfA\x1e\x7f\xb6Z'
```

and this is my instruction

```
sudo python3 ./RsaCtfTool.py -n 50142032499469550407421604706771611415193641755639270667473328045908799316205905505167271138079522738272643811917325451177986948493659090203974349370248583120022500722759239305447823602875823849366662503027591858371125301505134216095903796534740686834236150999 -e 65537 --uncipher 45005399504992587510006608300548120810512973768886391125598523343330913326304417790989607300367232977960116381108873363343598357102136548218343380795022179607741940866191404186680657699739176842869814452906110393321567314747096161480003824583613027819960172221 --attack factordb
```

Is it my tool version question? Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot, warm and friendly people

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.

Comment: That's a 862-bit modulus. Must be something other than factoring...